# How to only unescape characters between <code> tags, except for <pre><code> tags?

Tags: wordpress, html-escape-characters

I used some code in WordPress Posts, but some characters have been escaped. Sometimes I just want `&lt;` keep showing like that, instead of `<`.

I am also currently using `prism.js`, so I want those code between `<pre><code>` and `</code></pre>` keep escaping, but those between `<code>` and `</code>` to unescape.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', function( $a ) {
    $a["extended_valid_elements"] = 'ADD TAGS YOU NEED TO BE ALLOWED IN THE EDITOR HERE';
    return $a
});
```